# how can i split the longest word in the sentence

Tags: java, string, split

```
String s = "сотрудник компании ГазТехСтройСнабСервис";
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

how can i split the longest word in the sentence for example if it has more than 10 characters and return String?

Comment: So in this case the longest word is `ГазТехСтройСнабСервис`, so how would it be split? You just want to return `ГазТехСтро`?

Comment: The question is unclear. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: How do you know after how many characters the word should be split? Do you have a lookup dict?

Comment: @Michael i want to wrap to the next line if the word has more than 10 characters

Answer (score 0):

With java8 -

```
int len = 10; //specify your length here

List<String> list = Stream.of(s.split(" ")).filter(str->len > str.length()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

list will have all the words having length greater than the specified length.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right you want to split at each space or if a word has more than n chars at index n. Try something like this:

```
    int size = 10;
    String s = "сотрудник компании ГазТехСтройСнабСервис";
    String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+size+"})|\\s+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Comment: how to write like this "сотрудник компании ГазТех- to the next line СтройСнабСервис"